# How to configure bspwm with home-manager

Tags: x11, xorg, nixos, dot-files, bspwm

I'm using nixos and trying to configure bspwm with home-manager. However, whenever I attempt to login using xorg, it fails saying "Failed to start session". Does anybody know anything about this? My home manager config is at https://termbin.com/zjjx.